# Google Sheet Countifs with Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm planning to create a dynamic cell which can count total items or only certain items.
I used the following formula to get the total items. But this formula doesn't work when I filter by item.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A;{“D1”;{“APPLE”;”ORANGE”;”POMEGRANATES”}};B:B;”1/6/2022″)))`

*D1 = Dropdown for Apple/Orange/Pineapple/Pomegranates

The result I expect is:

If I select Apple then the only value that appears is Apple (4/10).

- Apple = 4
- Orange = 3
- Pineapple = 1
- Pomegranates = 2

And
If I don’t select Apple then the values that appear are all values (10/10)

- All Fruit = 10

I would be very grateful if you could tell me where the error is and provide a solution.

[Demo Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dKiQga7yLeX8HG2j_v4wYR1eslmmkfQnSIUWG3lZmkw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
=QUERY(
  {A:B};
  "select Count(Col1)
   where
    Col1 matches '"&IF(ISBLANK(D1);".*";D1)&"' and
    Col2 = date '"&TEXT(DATE(2022;6;1);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
   label Count(Col1) ''")
```

If D1 is blank, it'll return everything (`.*` / the wildcard) -- otherwise it'll pull the word in D1.

If you wanted to use a cell reference for the date, you can replace `DATE(2022;6;1)` with that cell reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=sumproduct(regexmatch(A:A; IF(LEN(D1); D1; "Apple|Orange|Pomegranates|Pineapple")); B:B= date(2022; 6; 1))
```

and see if that works?

Note that regexmatch is case-sensitive.

Comment: This is interesting, both answers give different formulas but give the desired result.Thank you very much.